# How to make a tokio stream works concurrently

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I would like to run a sequence of streams with several processes of the stream running concurrently. The test code that I tried is the following:

```rust
use tokio;
use tokio_stream::{self as stream, StreamExt};
use std::time::Duration;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let stream = stream::iter(0..10)
        .then(|i| async move {
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            println!("i={:?}", i);
        })
        .chunks_timeout(3, Duration::from_secs(20));

    let _result : Vec<_> = stream
        .collect().await;
}
```

This code runs but it prints the 10 values one by one with a 1 second delay. This is the opposite of concurrency. What I would expect is that one wait 3 seconds, get 3 numbers printed, then wait 1 second and so on.
I think the `tokio::time::sleep` is fine as with a `join_all` I got the code working concurrently.

So what explains the lack of concurrency and what be done about it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Do you want all `sleep()`s to be executed at the same time, causing a sleep of 1s then immediate printing of ten numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Streams are simply asynchronous iterators and are lazy, they do not include additional per-element concurrency unless you ask for it.

The streaming functionality from [tokio-stream](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/latest/tokio_stream/) is simply a different flavor of that from the [futures](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/index.html) crate (which is probably more common). They both use the same underlying `Stream` trait. The differences lie in their respective `StreamExt` traits; [the one from from the futures crate](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html) is more fully featured and generic while [the the one from tokio-stream](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/latest/tokio_stream/trait.StreamExt.html) is more slim and geared towards tokio (and timing in particular).

You'll want to use [`.buffered()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffered)/[`buffered_unordered()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffer_unordered) from the futures crate since those methods allow the stream to buffer multiple pending futures at a time (thereby allowing them to run concurrently), but you'll still need [`.chunks_timeout()`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/latest/tokio_stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.chunks_timeout) from tokio-stream. Unfortunately, you can't have both traits in scope since many calls like `.then()` or `.map()` would be ambiguous; the best course would be to [follow the advice from tokio-stream](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/latest/tokio_stream/trait.StreamExt.html) and use the fully-qualified syntax for one of them.

Here's a full example (changed from `.then()` to `.map()` due to the way `.buffered()` works):

```
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let stream = stream::iter(0..10)
        .map(|i| async move {
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            println!("i={:?}", i);
        })
        .buffered(5);

    let stream = tokio_stream::StreamExt::chunks_timeout(stream, 3, Duration::from_secs(20));

    let _result: Vec<_> = stream.collect().await;
}
```

This code would complete in approximately two seconds since it will run five out of the ten sleeps concurrently at a time.